# Reset the IM font settings - Skype for Business

Tags: fonts, skype-for-business

I accidentally changed the **IM**'s font settings. Now I want to reset back to default. I didn't find any **Reset to Default** option there.

[image: Skype for business IM settings]

My expectation is:

- Any button to 'Reset to Default' font settings?

or

- May I know the default font name, font size (so I can set it manually).

**Version**: Skype for Business 2015

Comment: Even to date, we are in July 2020, there is no shortcut to 'Reset to Default' exists. It totally sucks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the default settings :

[image: Settings]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any documentation available to ensure the above are the default settings?

Comment: Heh not really. Just know that we started to deploy Skype for Business in my company and i didn't change the settings.

Comment: Because I refereed this [`link`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-font-in-your-instant-messages-745edc6d-5089-4e4e-8689-75b39ee5326d), from this I can't understand the default settings clearly. Whether the default font size is 9 or 10.

Comment: I re-installed the application again and the found the settings you are shared are default.